# Node.js MySQL unknown column in field list

Tags: mysql, node.js

Консоль выдает ошибку unknown column 'Tomas' in 'field list'

```
 var name = "Tomas",
        password = "Cat";

  var mysql = require('mysql');

  var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "password",
    database: "mydb"
  });

  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    var sql = `INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES (${name},${password})`;
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 record inserted");
    });
  });
```

Таблица пустая, создавал так:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "password",
  database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "CREATE TABLE customers (name VARCHAR(255), address VARCHAR(255))";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Table created");
  });
});
```

Comment: У вас там и колонка называется "Tomas", и значение вы вставляете "Tomas"? Уверены, что вы именно этого хотите?

Comment: Спасибо большое, прозевал =)

Comment: к сожалению, это проблему не решило...

Comment: Схему бд покажите.

Comment: добавил в описание

Comment: Запрос вижу на создание, схемы не вижу. Судя по вашему запросу у таблицы названия колонок должны быть "name" и "address". В таком случае ошибки такой быть не должно. Попробуйте в кавычки аргументы взять ``INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES ("${name}","${password})"``

Comment: Теперь добавляет данные в таблицу без проблем. Спасибо!
А что Вы имели ввиду под схемой и как ее получить?

Comment: Изображение базы данных со связями между таблицами. Что-то типо такого https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/images/employees-schema.png

Comment: Ясно, еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Нужно переменный в кавычки взять.

```
INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES ("${name}","${password})"
```

Насколько я понимаю, пример [отсюда](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_insert.asp). Там аргументы строковые взяты в кавычки (:

Comment: А лучше пользоваться экранированием https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/master/Readme.md#escaping-query-values